# Can anyone tell me why my installation of nuxt 3 has ENOENT ERROR?

Tags: error-handling, nuxt3

0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@9.7.2
2 info using node@v20.4.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 4ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 3ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 5ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 5ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:D:\CAPSTONE42.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 2ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\umbik.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\umbik\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load Completed in 14ms
17 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 14ms
18 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 1ms
20 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
21 verbose title npm exec nuxi@latest init fitfinder-frontend
22 verbose argv "exec" "--" "nuxi@latest" "init" "fitfinder-frontend"
23 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 2ms
24 timing npm:load:display Completed in 1ms
25 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\umbik\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-12T12_18_09_558Z-
26 verbose logfile C:\Users\umbik\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-12T12_18_09_558Z-debug-0.log
27 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 11ms
28 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
29 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
30 timing npm:load Completed in 58ms
31 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
32 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 4 files
33 silly logfile done cleaning log files
34 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/nuxi 1241ms (cache revalidated)
35 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
36 timing command:exec Completed in 1279ms
37 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\umbik\AppData\Roaming\npm'
38 verbose cwd D:\CAPSTONE42
39 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.21996
40 verbose node v20.4.0
41 verbose npm  v9.7.2
42 error code ENOENT
43 error syscall lstat
44 error path C:\Users\umbik\AppData\Roaming\npm
45 error errno -4058
46 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\umbik\AppData\Roaming\npm'
47 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
47 error enoent
48 verbose exit -4058
49 timing npm Completed in 2086ms
50 verbose code -4058
51 error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\umbik\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-12T12_18_09_558Z-debug-0.log

Can anyone please tell me why is this happening whenever I try to create a nuxt 3 project on my windows 11 environment

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `npx nuxi@latest init my-app`?
Might be your node version installed is not yet compatible or it's a new bug on node 20. You can try to use a different node version, maybe node version 18 or 19 for the meantime (it's stable) and also report this issue to the nuxt team (see the github issue below), it would be helpful for the community.

References:
https://nuxt.com/blog/v3#the-browser-and-nodejs-support
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/20445

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same error. After searching on Google, I found my error. This is node.js and local NPM installation. We need to install NPM globally.
**npm install -g npm**
So we will not get any error while installing nuxt3 package.